# Pandas - TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set up a simple DataFrame in pandas that imports data from a JSON file, specifically from Alpha Vantage. I'm looking to fix the function sectorperformance, as microsoft runs just fine without the error. 
JSON File for sector:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SECTOR&apikey=demo

I'm new to pandas so I've tried to change up a few lines of code with no success. I'm sure I am missing something basic but can't find it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime
api_key = open("APIkey.txt", "r").read()

def microsoft():
    data = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=' + api_key)
    data = data.json()
    data = data['Time Series (5min)']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
    for d,p in data.items():
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        data_row = [date, float(p['1. open']), float(p['2. high']), float(p['3. low']), float(p['4. close']), int(p['5. volume'])]
        df.loc[-1, :] = data_row
        df.index = df.index + 1
    data = df.sort_values('date')
    df["diff"] = df["close"].diff(-1)
    df["range"] = df["high"] - df["low"]
    print(df)

def sectorperformance():
    data = requests.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SECTOR&apikey=" + api_key)
    data = data.json()
    data = data['Rank B: 1 Day Performance']
    print(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Industrials', 'Consumer Discretionary', 'Materials', 'Information Technology', 'Communication Services', 'Financials', 'Energy', 'Consumer Staples', 'Real Estate', 'Utilities', 'Health Care'])
    for p in data.items():
        data_row = [float(p['Industrials']), float(p['Consumer Discretionary']), float(p['Materials']), float(p['Information Technology']), float(p['Communication Services']), float(p['Financials']), float(p['Energy']), float(p['Consumer Staples']), float(p['Real Estate']), float(p['Utilities']), float(p['Health Care'])]
        df.loc[-1, :] = data_row
        df.index = df.index + 1
    print(df)

sectorperformance()


TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This error is only received with sectorperformance and not microsoft, but both functions are very similar.

Comment: Show the full error with trace, and note what debugging you've done and where you've narrowed the problem down to.

Comment: data.items() gives you a tuple that you save to p in sectorperformance and then you index p with some strings. Also what the other guy said about how your post should be improved is totally true

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hard to say without the full stack trace, but I'm going to go ahead and guess data.items() when iterated over within sectorperformance yields tuples when you expected it to be a dictionary.

The data you're receiving might be in a different format than what you expected.